# Wanting attic antenna for LF and HF receiving

Tags: antenna, ham-radio

I know next to nothing about antennas and am hoping someone can tell me what antenna I need to pick up ham radio and FM signals on an attic mount antenna. I will have no need to transmit. My attic peak is 6-7 feet and I live on high ground (no mountains, hills) out in the country. Can I use a UHF/VHF antenna?

Comment: Plenty of information is available with a web search. Question should be closed - insufficient research.

Comment: This question is too broad and too end-user oriented to fit here.  You need to consult existing books and online resource on shortware listening and ham radio.  For reception the consequences of an unmatched antenna are less critical than they are from transmission; weak signal performance will be somewhat reduced, but you aren't going to overheat the final amplifier since none is involved.

Comment: You will get more relevant answers on the amateur radio stack exchange:  https://ham.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Any amount of conductor you can string in your attic will work as a receiving antenna for LF & HF.  The downside of having the antenna in the attic is noise pickup.  Every lamp dimmer, computer, and electronic appliance with a switching power supply will generate RF noise that will be detected by your receiver.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a few feet of wire as a receive antenna, either a dipole or a monopole with a ground plane. The main issue with a short antenna at LF and MF is impedance matching. It will have a very high (capacitive) impedance and the mismatch loss into 50 ohms will be high. Impedance matching can be done with a transformer or a JFET input amplifier. Look up active receive antenna on the web. 
You can also use a loop with a number of turns. In the early days of radio these were called frame aerials.